# Background image not showing on page

Tags: css, background-image

my background image is not showing. Here's the CSS:

```
.banner {
    height: 25em;
    width: 100%;
    background: #F0F3F7 url("images/Dog_02.jpg");
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<article class = "section group">
    <section class = "banner col span_8_of_8">
```

The background color does show up but the image does not. I've checked the Developer Tools in Google Chrome. It lists no errors.

Comment: Are you putting the correct path to the image inside the `url` for the `background`?

Comment: Would you please update your original question with the path your image is saved in?

Comment: your code works here on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fw9k5fbw/

Answer (score 1):

[image]i try this demo working please try, your problems is not putting the correct path to the `url` for the `background image`

```
.banner {
        height: 25em;
        width: 100%;
        background:url("images/Desert.jpg");
        background-size: cover; 
    }
```

// your body portion

```
<article class = "section group">
    <section class = "banner col span_8_of_8">
    </section>
</article>
```